# How to install pygame on Mac with python 2.7 installed?

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I want to install pygame on Mac 10.6.8.
I managed to install python 2.7.9 and to make it stable.
I tried to install different versions of pygame but none worked: for example with the 1.9.1 it gives me this error:

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/.../Desktop/example.py", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

I don't know if it is a problem of computer architecture (32/64 bit) or because the versions of python and pygame do not match.

I tried to look further in the official site of pygame but did not solve a thing.

Did anyone have the same problem? How to solve it?

Please note that I have already taken a look at other similar questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me, after a lot of searching, is described [in this link](http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x/), using homwbrew and pip.

- install XQuarts if not already installed from the site
- install homebrew ([link here](http://brew.sh))
- install python3 with the command `brew install python3` in the terminal
- install the Mercurial version control system: `brew install mercurial`
- do the same for the git version control system, which is needed by a dependency package: `brew install git`
- Now install all the dependencies of Pygame: `brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf smpeg portmidi`
- install `pip` with the command `/usr/local/share/python3/easy_install pip` (in my case the folder was `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/bin`)
- `/usr/local/share/python3/pip install hg`+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are some binary incompatible issue. Maybe you can download the source and compile it: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

Comment: I have tried and I get this error:

ld: in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/Library/Frameworks//smpeg.framework/smpeg, missing required architecture x86_64 in file for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//ccphUjIL.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1